# Como chamar uma função de um arquivo.js no proprio index.php no script

Tags: javascript, html

Gostaria de saber como, eu chamo uma função de um arquivo x.js, em uma pagina x.html x.php tanto faz.

Exemplo:

**Arquivo x.js:**

```
function myFunction(img){
    // Faz algo
}
```

**Arquivo index.php:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>

    <script>

        myFunction("algo.jpg"); // <-- como fazer uma função de um arquivo js, aceitar eu chamar ela em um arquivo index.php?

    </script>
</head>
<body>
     <img src="img/algo.jpg" alt="">

     <script src="x.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: convem incluir o arquivo com `<script src="x.js"></script>`

Comment: isso, mas não é isso que eu quis dizer, estou dizendo que mesmo colocando isso, a função acima não funciona

Comment: Por outro motivo qualquer, não é por causa de ser php. O que era suposto a função fazer?

Comment: Não, index.php foi só um exemplo poderia ser .html .jsp enfim, eu gostaria que ao criar uma função em um ARQUIVO.JS eu conseguisse chamar essa função no meu ARQUIVO.HTML/PHP ETC pelo <script></script>, a questão é que, eu preciso passar imagens para essa função, e cada página vai ter uma imagem diferente, então em cada página eu preciso chamar essa função passando como parâmetro o nome dessas imagens

Comment: O problema não está na chamada a função. O exemplo que tem funciona perfeitamente independentemente de ser `php`, `jsp`, `html` ou o que seja, assumindo que está a incluir o ficheiro `js` como eu mencionei. Se for o caso o problema está no que tá a tentar fazer especificamente dentro da função, que lhe não lhe está a funcionar e o leva a pensar que a função não está a ser chamada. Aproveite e confirme se tem erros no browser, que lhe devem dar logo para despistar se o ficheiro está a ser incluido corretamente

Comment: O Wéllingthon M. de Souza, resolveu o problema, era só isso que precisava, só que eu não enchergava uma coisa tão simples, valeu Isac, por tentar me ajudar também

Comment: Foi a primeira coisa que comecei por indicar, a inclusão do ficheiro lol, naturalmente assumi que sabia onde a colocar

Comment: Sim kk, uma coisa tão simples né, estava na minha cara e não percebi, coisa básica, mas... faz parte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso é muito comum por aqui, e a questão esta ordem, você esta tentando acessar uma método que ainda não consta no documento, porque você está importando o arquivo *Javascript* no final do documento.

Faça o seguinte coloque a linha

```
<script src="x.js"></script>
```

Antes de:

```
<script>

    myFunction("algo.jpg"); // <-- como fazer uma função de um arquivo js, aceitar eu chamar ela em um arquivo index.php?

</script>
```

> Veja funcionando em [plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co/edit/bKKjc7ALV1YcDlfbyJDv?p=preview)

Comment: Bingo, estáva em cima de minha face e eu não percebi, coisa básica do básico, Valeu Wéllingthon !!